# Connecting Php application with MySQL Fabric (using php aware connector)

Tags: php, mysql, sharding, mysql-fabric

I have implemented MySQL Sharding using MySQL Fabric as following steps:

Steps: 
1. Install latest (mysql-utilities-1.5.2 utility) for MySQL Fabric and enable mysqlnd_ms for php-aware-connector
2. Set up and manage MySQL Fabric
3. Create group (global, shard groups) and add server into groups
4. Define database schema and tables , range all for shard the database/table
5. Enable GTID all servers as per requirement
5. Verify and Test using command  (mysqlfabric sharding lookup_servers database_name.table_name 100000), It ping the right servers as I need

**Issue**: I am not able to connect PHP application with MySQL Fabric, but the same set up of MySQL Fabric if I use with python application(its connector) works fine.

I got this error while connecting php application to MySQL Fabric:

```
Warning:  mysqlnd_ms_fabric_select_shard(): (mysqlnd_ms) Didn't receive usable servers from MySQL Fabric in /var/www/html/shard.php on line 49

Warning:  mysqli::query(): (mysqlnd_ms) Couldn't find the appropriate master connection. 0 masters to choose from. Something is wrong in /var/www/html/shard.php on line 53

Warning:  mysqli::query(): (mysqlnd_ms) No connection selected by the last filter in /var/www/html/shard.php on line 53

[2000] (mysqlnd_ms) No connection selected by the last filter
```

Comment: What error do you get when connecting with PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently MySQL Router is now the way to go to connect PHP to Fabric:

http://mysqlhighavailability.com/mysql-router-on-labs-the-newest-member-of-the-mysql-family/

Instead of providing individual fabric functionality in each connector, they have factored it into an external component which can be used transparently with any existing connector.